# String translator into MIPS

Tags: string, loops, assembly, mips

I have to make a String Translator in MIPS that receive a String in input and prints its translation by this rule:

Substrings "uno" "due" "tre" "quattro" "cinque" "sei" "sette" "otto" "nove" are translated in '1', '2', '3',...,'9'.
Spaces (empty chars) in the Input String represent the end of a substring.
All substrings not written up here, are translated in '?'.
So, this is my code:

```
.data
msg: .asciiz "Inserisci una stringa \n"
output: .asciiz "La traduzione Ã¨: \n"
string: .space 100
uno: .asciiz "uno"
due: .asciiz "due"
tre: .asciiz "tre"
quattro: .asciiz "quattro"
cinque: .asciiz "cinque"
sei: .asciiz "sei"
sette: .asciiz "sette"
otto: .asciiz "otto"
nove: .asciiz "nove"
.text
.globl main
main:
li $s7,0
la $t4,uno
la $t5,due
la $t6,tre
la $t8,quattro
la $t9,cinque
la $s3,sei
la $s4,sette
la $s5,otto
la $s6,nove
la $a0,msg
li $v0,4
syscall
input: 
la $a0,string
li $a1,100
li $v0,8
syscall
li $s0, 0
scorriStringa: 
move $t7,$s0
lb $t1, string($s0)
addi $s0,$s0,1
bne $t1,32,scorriStringa #here there's always a loop
beq $t1,'o',uscita
controlloSpazi:
lb $t2,string($s0)
addi $s0,$s0,1
beq $t2,32,controlloSpazi
subi $s0,$s0,1
traduzione:
move $s1,$t7
scorriSS:
lb $t3,string($s1)
confrontoUno:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$t4,confrontoDue
confrontoDue:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$t5,confrontoTre
confrontoTre:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$t6,confrontoQuattro
confrontoQuattro:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$t8,confrontoCinque
confrontoCinque:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$t9,confrontoSei
confrontoSei:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$s3,confrontoSette
confrontoSette:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$s4,confrontoOtto
confrontoOtto:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$s5,confrontoNove
confrontoNove:
addi $s7,$s7,1
bne $t3,$s6,confrontoNull
confrontoNull:
li $s7,0
j stampaNull
dopoConf:
addi $s1,$s1,1
beq $s1,$s0 stampaN
bne $s1,$s0, scorriSS
j scorriStringa
stampaN:
beq $s7,0,stampaUno
beq $s7,1,stampaDue
beq $s7,2,stampaTre
beq $s7,3,stampaQuattro
beq $s7,4,stampaCinque
beq $s7,5,stampaSei
beq $s7,6,stampaSette
beq $s7,7,stampaOtto
beq $s7,8,stampaNove
dopoStampe:
li $s1,0
li $s2,0
j scorriStringa
uscita:
li $v0,10
syscall
stampaUno:
li $a0,1
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaDue:
li $a0,2
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaTre:
li $a0,3
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaQuattro:
li $a0,4
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaCinque:
li $a0,5
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaSei:
li $a0,6
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaSette:
li $a0,7
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaOtto:
li $a0,8
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaNove:
li $a0,9
li $v0,1
syscall
j dopoStampe
stampaNull:
li $a0,'?'
li $v0,4
syscall
j dopoStampe
```

I don't know why my code make this loop! Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: format your question!

Comment: @RachelGallen I edited it. Maybe next time you could go through the trouble too :)

Comment: Thank you! You did it while I was editing the post ;)

Comment: Why have all those labels and `BEQ`s? You could make all strings 8 bytes in size and calculate the address of the string to print as `first_string + (number << 3)`.

Comment: what "this loop" do you refer to?  the jump at the end, j dopoStampe? What is your program supposed to do instead of a loop?

Comment: bne $t1,32,scorriStringa <--- the program always jump to scorriStringa but program must find almost one ' ' (so 32) char! 
In this point I have to read all chars that they are ' ' because they are valid parts of a substring i have to translate ! Thank you